# How to Practice Pull-ups without Equipment

Tags: pull-ups

I want to work up to doing more pull-ups, but have access to only a very minimal gym (i.e., without a pull-up bar), and then no gym after that, for a month.

What are the best ways to work the muscles needed for pull-ups without access to any equipment (e.g., bars, weights, bands, jungle-gyms, etc.)?

Comment: This is a really good question, and one I've struggled with myself (I'm a big fan of pullups). I'll see about writing my thoughts and experiences in the matter later.

Answer (score 9):

If you have nothing to pull yourself up to, the next best thing is rowing.

The two most practical kinds of rows without a gym are:

**inverted rows**
which can be done under a table

[image: inverted row]

and **dumbbell rows**
which you can do with various heavy objects that have a handle, like a bottle-crate (preferably the kind that has the handle in the middle).

[image]

But you should still go outside and find yourself some bar to to a pull-up with, like on a playground. Carry-over from a similar exercise is not as good as the real thing.

Comment: The pulling up on a table is a good one. The dumbbells could be replaced with a heavy suitcase or a large canister of water/sand. Good suggestions!

Answer (score 5):

[Here's a link](http://www.dudewheresmymuscle.com/chin-up-alternatives/) to some 'alternatives'.

I use an [iron gym pull up bar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EJMS6K) that fits in a door frame. I need to tuck my legs up, but find it challenging and provides for pull/chin and neutral ups. I'm 6' 215 lbs – so it's stable.

Comment: +1 on the iron gym pull up bar, I'm 6'4" 285 lbs and it supports my lardy self. I can't do pull-ups yet, but I'm getting there :D

Comment: How much pressure does the iron gym pull up bar put on the door trim on the outsides of the door. My door trim is pretty crappy and I don't want to pull the bar down on myself.