# exercise that can replace Pull-up?

Tags: pull-ups, arms

I wonder, if there's a way to work out the arms similar to pull-up exercise, but without using pull-up bars?

Indoor exercises are convenient. I could just do push-ups in the living room. However, there's no bar in my flat and also cannot use pull-up bars due to the limit of the doors. I'm afraid only doing push-ups will make my arms unbalanced developed.

Is there a way to work out those "pull-up muscles"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Practice Pull-ups without Equipment](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3157/how-to-practice-pull-ups-without-equipment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a table, you can do inverted rows. Get into a lying position under the table, hands holding the edge of the table. Pull yourself up to the table and repeat. It's easier than an actual pull-up (in fact, it's usually recommended for people who can't do pull-ups yet), but it exercises many of the same muscles.

More information is available in [How to Practice Pull-ups without Equipment](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3157/how-to-practice-pull-ups-without-equipment?rq=1) on this site.

Comment: This movement sounds a little risky.  Be careful.

Comment: True. It is important to ensure that the table is stable.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're referring to doing reverse pull-ups to work the biceps.  If so, purchasing a dumbbell set would provide you with more opportunity to expand your workouts. Additionally, exercise bands can work for you. If your budget is a concern, then, find a heavy can of food that you can grip with your hand.  That's a free substitute for a dumbbell.